# class precedence css h1

Tags: css

can you explain why h1.smaller-20 does not take precedence over .hm-share h1 ?
And how can I make all the h1.smaller-20 the same size on my website ?

[image]

```
<hm-logo-bar left-cb="ctrl.skip()" left-name="'Passer'"></hm-logo-bar>
<ion-content  scroll="false" class="hm-share">
  <div ng-if="ctrl.step == 1">
    <div class="hm-container">
      <h1>{{'share.0' | translate}}</h1>
      <h1>{{'share.1' | translate}}</h1>
      <h1 class="smaller-20">{{'share.2' | translate}}</h3>
    </div>
    ...
```

Comment: try to use `!important` to prevent override : `font-size:1.42857rem!important`

Comment: They have the same precedence (one tag name, one class) so whichever appears later in the CSS file wins.

Comment: @לבנימלכה: while the use of `!important` can be useful to ensure that the selector is correct it should *not* be used outside of that - minor - diagnostic function. Instead use the cascade properly.

Comment: ok thanks everyone, so the best practices are to use !important ?

Comment: the worst practise is !important ... the best practise is to understand how CSS work and you will be able to re-order you style and add/remove some classes to have what you want

Comment: I agree with Temani Afif to your question if is `!important` best pracites.... here is learn:https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: ok thanks. So it I want to put general css at the begining of my css file, in order to style all smaller h1s, what is the best practices please ?

Comment: Best practice is to put your own specific styles last. If you can't do that for whatever reason, make sure the specificity of your desired behaviour is higher. You can write, for instance, `body h1.className` to override `h1.className`.